# row index and column index of a value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I have a table and it has few values. I've assigned the highest value to a variable. Now I want to get the row index and column index of the cell that contain the value in the variable. How is it possible? I need to use jquery only.Any help is appreciated. Thnankyou.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: When you are assigning variables, theoretically you should know the row index and column index, otherwise how to assign it? You can share more of your code and supplement the details of the problem

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#submit_vote").click(function()
  {
   var i=1;

    // $("#div2").hide();
    // $("#div3").show();

    //find winner

    max_vote = $('#input_count'+0).val();

  $("#lastTable tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function (i)
    {  
   winner = $('#input_count'+i).val();
   if (winner > max_vote)
   {
    max_vote = winner;
   }
  });

  // alert(max_vote);

    $("#lastTable tr td").each(function (j)
    {
     var row_index = $(max_vote).parent().index();
  var col_index = $(max_vote).index();
    });
 });});

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided a reproducible code example,i have a code snippet for you,so you can modify it for your own needs,it gives you the cell index + row index of the highest number among all td cells,its not what you want but it gives you the logic you should follow (my opinion)

Keep in mind that indexes start at 0 (0,1,2,3...)

```js
let allTd = []

document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td =>{
allTd.push(Number(td.innerText))
}) //create an array of all the numbers in td cells

let max = Math.max(...allTd) // find the highest number

document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => {
  if (Number(td.innerText) === max) { 
  console.log(`Row index : ${td.closest("tr").sectionRowIndex}`) 
  console.log(`Cell index : ${td.closest("td").cellIndex}`)
  }
}) //compare highest number against all td cells then console.log row index and cell index of matching cell
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>17</td>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>77</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```